# How to prove $f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing, radicals, nested-radicals

I've been working on this question for over 2 hours now and I tried to use the limit definition of a derivative to show that it's differentiable but that got me nowhere because I was completely incapable of simplifying the expression I got. If anyone has any leads as to how to start/continue the proof, please explain how I should approach this.
Also, I should be able to compute the derivative simply after I prove that it's differentiable, right?
(I'm really sorry about this but I've been doing pretty bad in my real analysis course so I'm genuinely just not sure of what I'm doing anymore)

EDIT: What I did was this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Tjm.jpg)

I've tried to simplify this by using a few methods, but basically yeah I'm stuck at the first step...

EDIT2: This is the question:[image: question]

Comment: Have you tried using that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable (this is one of the reasons you can calculate this derivative using the chain rule) ? On what domain do you need to show that this is differentiable?

Comment: Please show us what you wrote while working on this question, to depict and verify what you tried. That will help us better understand what might have gone wrong.  Saying "I tried a, b c but it got me nowhere, is not the same as showing us your attempts.

Comment: @DanielMourad Oh wait no, I haven't tried that yet, but I'll see if it works. Also, f goes from R≥0 → R. Would that make a difference in how to prove it?

Comment: @amWhy alright I'm adding it in the post

Comment: Thanks, Applesauce44!

Comment: @amWhy I'm not sure if this is even what I'm supposed to be doing, but the main thing that I was trying to work with is in the image...

Comment: That helps us understand your thought process, and where you might have been confused.  There's absolutely no shame in asking a question and showing work you did that left you feeling like you hit a dead.  But doing so helps us help *you* best.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think [that function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29%29) is differentiable at $x=0$. Are you sure you have the domain right?

Comment: @TonyK the question just states that we have to determine whether or not it's differentiable, not at any specific point, but just if it's differentiable The domain is what I wrote above, but I'm adding a picture of the question itself just in case though, if it helps understand the question better?

Comment: Apple, the only reasonable answer to whether $f$ is differentiable is "Yes, except at $x=0$." (The question would make more sense if the domain was specified as $\Bbb R_{>0}$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ as a composition of differentiable functions.

But it is not differentiable at $x=0$ : indeed
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}{x} \geq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
so
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}{x} = +\infty$$

Comment: What does the asterisk '*' in $\mathbb{R_{+}^{*}}$ signify?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_+^* = (0, +\infty)$. The asterisk means that you forget $0$.

Comment: Then, isn't that the same thing as either $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ or $\mathbb{R^+}$?

Comment: It depends : for me (in France), $\mathbb{R}_+ = [0, +\infty)$, and $\mathbb{R}_+^* = (0, +\infty)$. But maybe some people denotes  $\mathbb{R}_+ = (0, +\infty)$, I don't know.

Comment: wait, just as a clarification, why did you divide it by x?

Comment: @Applesauce44 Because you ask for a derivative...

Comment: Very interesting thanks.  I *have* been using $\mathbb{R^+}$ to signify $(0, +\infty).$  I suspect that there is an international difference.

Comment: @user2661923 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_real_numbers

Comment: Thanks: therefore, I am not a practicing mathematician.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Okay so I'm really sorry about this, but exactly which differentiable functions is this a composition of? Not sure if this sounds dumb, but what did you use exactly to get the first expression...?
But also thank you so much for answering the question jbtw!!

Comment: For $g,h : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$, your function is $h \circ (g + h\circ (g +h))$. This invloves composition and sum of differentiable functions, so it is differentiable over $(0, +\infty)$.

Comment: OHHHH okay I think I get it now, thank youu!!

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the calculation of the derivative I write
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\sqrt{x+g(x)};\;g(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}};\;x\ge 0$$
We have $$f'(x) =\frac{g'(x)+1}{2 \sqrt{g(x)+x}}$$
where $$g'(x) =\frac{2 \sqrt{x}+1}{4 \sqrt{x^{3/2}+x^2}}$$
so finally
$$f'(x) =\frac{\frac{2 \sqrt{x}+1}{4 \sqrt{x^{3/2}+x^2}}+1}{2 \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$$